# The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot be rolled back to a savepoint. Roll back the entire transaction - 'Msg 3931, Level 16, State 1

Tags: sql, t-sql, transactions, sql-server-2014

I use SQL Server 2014 and I have run this test T/SQL.

```
    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRANSACTION T1

        CREATE TABLE aa9
        (
            A int
        )

        SAVE TRANSACTION S1

        INSERT INTO aa9 (A) VALUES ('aa')

        COMMIT TRANSACTION T1

    END TRY 
    BEGIN CATCH 
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION S1
        PRINT 'Error ..... '
        ;throw
    END CATCH
```

Why do I get this error:

> Msg 3931, Level 16, State 1, Line 17
>   The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot be rolled back to a savepoint. Roll back the entire transaction.

Should I be able to Rollback the transaction to my SavePoint transaction?

Comment: I believe you save transaction before you start the next one.  Try putting the save transaction before the being transaction.

Comment: @Hogan : You can not Save Transaction when there is not any active transaction. this is error : Msg 628, Level 16, State 0, Line 2
Cannot issue SAVE TRANSACTION when there is no active transaction. What you have said has no sense.

Comment: It makes perfect sense -- first check and see if there is an active transaction -- then save it -- then start your next one.  There is no reason to save a transaction if you are not starting a new one.

Answer (score 0):

You can really only rollback Save Transactions if your XACT_State() isn't -1.
This doesn't really apply to Insert Statements as that will blow the XACT_State() of all the transactions even if you rollback the save point.
So you can use it for stuff like Dividing By Zero and Conversion Errors but SQL Server isn't as sophisticated as you would hope.

However you can get some form of nested transactions as provided you add a bunch of checking as shown below.

Obligatory link to MSDN:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/xact-state-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS aa9;
BEGIN TRANSACTION T2;
BEGIN TRY
    CREATE TABLE aa9
    (
        A int
    )
    PRINT 'Starting T2'

    SAVE TRANSACTION T2;
    INSERT INTO aa9(A) VAlUES (1);
    PRINT 'Starting T3'
    BEGIN TRANSACTION T3
    SAVE TRANSACTION T3
    BEGIN TRY
        INSERT INTO aa9 (A) VALUES (2)
        PRINT 'Forcing Error that doesn''t blow XACT_STATE()'
        SELECT 1/0 --Comment This Line  To See Difference
        INSERT INTO aa9(A) VALUES ('A')
        PRINT 'Committing T3'
        COMMIT TRANSACTION T3
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
            PRINT 'Rolling Back T3'
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION T3;
            THROW
    END CATCH
    COMMIT TRANSACTION T2;
END TRY 
BEGIN CATCH 
    IF XACT_STATE() = -1
    BEGIN
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    PRINT 'Error ..... '
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
     COMMIT TRANSACTION T2;
     PRINT 'Preserving T2..... '

    END;
    throw
END CATCH 
GO
SELECT * FROM aa9
```